# Integer.parseint in Java, exception when '+' comes first

Tags: java

`Integer.parseInt("-1000");` returns -1000 as the output.

`Integer.parseInt("+500");` throws an exception.

How will I be able to recognize positive numbers with the "+" symbol before them 
without having to trim the symbol?

Comment: What's the problem with trimming the symbol?

Comment: That you shouldn't have to?

Comment: Why not use regex to parse out the +, and leave the -?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) like with the pattern `"+#;-#"`. It will handle explicit signed parsing. Breakdown of the pattern:

- The first part (before `;`) is the positive pattern, it has to start with an `+` char
- The second part is the negative and has to start with a `-` char

---

Example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("+#;-#");
System.out.println(df.parse("+500"));
System.out.println(df.parse("-500"));
```

Outputs:

```
500
-500
```

Comment: It seems impossible to get a DecimalFormat that can parse "+1" as 1, "-1" as -1, and "0" as 0.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use Java 7... assuming that behaves [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29):

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.

It looks like this was a new feature introduced into Java 7 though. The [JDK 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) docs only indicate that `-` is handled.

Answer (score 5):

The method is behaving as described in the documentation:

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value.

You need to skip the first character if it is a `+` to do the parse correctly:

```
if (s.charAt(0) == '+') s = s.substring(1);
int val= Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Comment: The OP says *"without having to trim the symbol ?"*

Comment: Yes i meant without having to handle the "+" symbol explicitely. Any way thanks for answering. I think the decimal format answer will suit.

Comment: @Achilles Yeah, the `DecimalFormat` one is a good answer indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Java 7, and `Integer.parseInt("+500");` is not throwing any exception.

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first 
>       character may be an ASCII minus sign `'-'` (`'\u002D'`) to indicate a negative value 
>       or an ASCII plus sign `'+'` (`'\u002B'`) to indicate a positive value.

[Java 7 documentation for Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: in case of java 6 only "-" is handled. 
so u can change your jre or change in ur code .

Answer (score 0):

> public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException
>
> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation has changed from java 6 to 7. Intger.parseInt("+500") used to Exception till java 6 , but works perfectly fine with java 7